# What happens when I give an offset to a "temporary register" in MIPS

Tags: mips

For example:

```
    $t0 = A
    $t1 = B
    $t2 = C
```

If I do the following command

```
 lw $t1, 4($t0)
```

would it load `$t2` into `$t1`?

Answer (score 0):

As long as your temporary registers are next to each other in memory.
i.e.

```
 Reference:   $t1                     $t2
 Mem Blocks: [byte][byte][byte][byte][byte][byte][byte][byte]...
```

Programs like [Logisim](http://www.cburch.com/logisim/) should have the registers packed tightly.

Helpful page [here](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61c/resources/MIPS_Green_Sheet.pdf) from UC Berkeley.

Answer (score 0):

> If I do the following command
>
> ```
> lw $t1, 4($t0)
> ```
>
> would it load $t2 into $t1?

No, it would not. The `lw` instruction is used to load data from memory, *not* to copy the value of one register into another register. To quote from the MIPS manual:

> `LW rt, offset(base)` **MIPS32 (MIPS I)**
>   **Purpose:**
>   To load a word from memory as a signed value
>
> **Description:** `rt ← memory[base+offset]`
>   The contents of the 32-bit word at the memory location specified by the aligned effective address are fetched,
>   sign-extended to the GPR register length if necessary, and placed in GPR *rt*. The 16-bit signed *offset* is added to the
>   contents of GPR *base* to form the effective address.

In other words, what `lw $t1, 4($t0)` does is form an effective address by adding the value of `$t0` with the value 4, and load a word (four bytes) from that address into register `$t1`.